# Django-Rest-Framework. Hyperlink entities via query parameters

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have two models: Field and Set. And I want to have hyperlink to Fields which compose concrete set.
**for example:**
url: `sets/` should return `[{'title': 'dimensional', 'fieldsLink': '#url-to-enpoin'}]`

There is nothing complicated to write something like this:

```
class Field(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    set = models.ForeignKey(Set, related_name='fields', blank=True, null=True)

class Set(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)


class SetSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    field_list = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(
        view_name='apiv1:setfields-list',
        lookup_field='slug')

    class Meta:
        model = Set
        fields = ('title', 'field_list')

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^fields/$', views.FieldView.as_view(), name='fields-list'),
    url(r'^sets/$', views.SetView.as_view(), name='sets-list'),
    url(r'^sets/(?P<slug>[\d\w\-]+)/fields/$', views.SetFieldView.as_view(), name='setfields-list'), # this url should be removed
)
```

But how can I hyperlink set to fields via url like `fields/?set=dimensional` (!query parameter) instead of `sets/dimensional/fields/` (argument in url)?

Is there any built-in way to do that instead of overriding `HyperlinkedIdentityField`?

Comment: There's no built in way as far as I know, I use similar solutions in my code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this two different ways: with a custom `HyperlinkedRelatedField` or a custom method on the serializer that is called.

[@kharandziuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1907902/kharandziuk) provided a custom field originally in the question.

```
class CustomHyperlinkedIdentityField(HyperlinkedIdentityField):

    def get_url(self, obj, view_name, request, format):
        from rest_framework.reverse import reverse
        lookup_field_value = getattr(obj, self.lookup_field, None)
        result = '{}?{}'.format(
            reverse(view_name, kwargs={}, request=request, format=format),
            urllib.urlencode({self.lookup_field: lookup_field_value})
        )
        return  result
```

If you don't want to create your own custom field, you can create a method on your serializer that returns the specific url. You could need to use a `SerializerMethodField`, and a method on your serializer similar to

```
def get_the_url(self, obj):
    return self.context["request"].build_absolute_url("/api/fields") + "?set=" + obj.title
```