# Django Rest Framework - URL With Query Parameters in Serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a `Story` and `Post` models, where a `Post` belongs to a `Story`. I want a URL to get all Posts associated with a given Story.

I was able to override the `get_queryset` of my `PostViewSet` in order to filter posts by story with URLs like `http://localhost:8000/posts/?story=1/`. This works beautifully if I type in the URL directly. Now I want to return this kind of url in my `StorySerializer`. I would like to be able to get Story responses that look like this

```
[
    {
        "url": "http://localhost:8000/stories/1/",
        "title": "Hero's Journey",
        "openings": 0,
        "date_created": "2020-06-28T16:53:35.150630Z",
        "posts": "http://localhost:8000/posts/?story=1/"
    },
    {
        "url": "http://localhost:8000/stories/2/",
        "title": "Halo 3",
        "openings": 0,
        "date_created": "2020-06-28T18:17:12.973586Z",
        "posts": "http://localhost:8000/posts/?story=2/"
    }
]
```

Is there DRF support for this kind of thing? I was trying to use a `HyperlinkedIdentityField` with `'post-list'` View in my `StorySerializer`, but I couldn't find a combination of parameters that would work. The current exception I get is
`AttributeError: 'Story' object has no attribute 'posts'`

**Serializers**

```
class StorySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    posts = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(
        view_name = 'post-list',
        many=True,
        lookup_field = 'pk',
        lookup_url_kwarg = 'story',
    )
    class Meta:
        model = models.Story
        fields = ['url', 'title', 'openings', 'date_created', 'posts']


class PostSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Post
        fields = ['url', 'story', 'user', 'text', 'date_created']
```

**Views**

```
class StoryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Story.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.StorySerializer


class PostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.PostSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = self.queryset
        story_id = self.request.query_params.get('story', None)
        if story_id is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(story=story_id)
        return queryset
```

**Models**

```
class Story(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    openings = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
    participant = models.ManyToManyField(User)


class Post(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    story = models.ForeignKey(
        Story,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

Comment: have you tried setting `related_name="posts"` in story field of Post model

Comment: @IgorMoraru That's a very neat shortcut for a common use case! It's not quite what I'm looking for, but that's something I was going to need soon!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a great solution here, overriding the get_url method to map 'pk' value to 'story' directly.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27584761/7308261

```
from rest_framework.reverse import reverse
import urllib

class StoryPostsHyperlinkedIdentityField(serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField):
    def get_url(self, obj, view_name, request, format):
        lookup_field_value = getattr(obj, self.lookup_field, None)
        result = '{}?{}'.format(
            reverse(view_name, kwargs={}, request=request, format=format),
            urllib.parse.urlencode({'story': lookup_field_value})
        )
        return result


class StorySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    posts = StoryPostsHyperlinkedIdentityField(
        view_name='post-list',
    )
    class Meta:
        model = models.Story
        fields = ['url', 'title', 'openings', 'date_created', 'posts']
```